# different criteria for columns in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

In my crystal report I need to give different criteria for each column to Display the data.
mainly Date Ranges.
eg. Column1 : criteria Date Between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-31'
    Column2 : criteria Date Less Than '2012-01-31'
    Column3 : criteria Date Equals to '2012-01-15'

is it possible to do this?
pls help me.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For column0, just add the {table.amount} field to the canvas.

Then add these formula fields:

```
//{@column1}
If {table.date} = Date(2012,1,1) Then {table.amount} Else 0

//{@column2}
If {table.date} IN Date(2012,1,1) TO Date(2012,1,31) Then {table.amount} Else 0

//{@column3}
If {table.date} < Date(2012,1,31) Then {table.amount} Else 0
```

Comment: hi,thanks for reply. my problem is ,in the first column all the Items in the Inventory table should display.related to these items,in the Second column,all the data until (2012,1,1) from the beginning in the system,should display.third column between (2012,1,1) and (2012,1,31).forth column,untill (2012,1,31) from the beginning should display.if there is no data then 0.